# How can I verify if TLS end-to-end encryption is configured properly?

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, encryption, tls1.2

I just tried to set up TLS on a django app hosted by Heroku PaaS. How can I verify if TLS was configured properly and that the communication is encrypted?

I tried:

```
curl -vI https://www.example.com
```

but I cannot tell if it is properly configured.

I tried:

```
heroku certs:info --app Appname
```

and it says

```
appname has no SSL certificates
```

If not set up properly but if I go to the url using chrome, I get the padlock symbol followed by 'secure'. What is going on? xD

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/